# list index out of range error python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm creating a bunch of lists that looks like this:

```
[ObjectId('542de00c763f4a7f558be1cf')]
[ObjectId('545284e7bf2e4ea2778b479d'), ObjectId('542de00c763f4a7f558be1d1')]
...etc
```

All of them have at least one item.  When I run this loop, however:

```
for agent_id in agent_ids:
    curs_obj = user_coll_obj.find({"agent_id" : str(agent_id)}).distinct("_id")
    temp_list=[]
    for obj in curs_obj:
        temp_list.append(obj)
    # print len(temp_list)
    print "len(temp_list) is" , len(temp_list)
    print "temp_list is" , temp_list
    print "temp_list[0] is", temp_list[0]
```

I get:

```
    print "temp_list[0] is", temp_list[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I comment out `print "temp_list[1] is", temp_list[0]` I get:

```
Len(temp_list) is 2
temp_list is [ObjectId('542de00c763f4a7f558be1cb'), ObjectId('54c123d2bf2e4e140e8b45fc')]
....etc.
```

Why am I getting the error?

Comment: what does `len(temp_list)` print right before the error?

Comment: Presumably your prints before that error show you a temp_list with values in it and a len > 0, right?

Comment: Try adding: `if len(temp_list) > 0:` before `print "temp_list[0] is", temp_list[0]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a loop, I'm assuming that at one point your query returns an empty list for a given agent_id which crashes the script at `temp_list[0]` since it's empty.

*off topic* mongo's `distinct` returns a list so there's no need to loop through it and append it to another list (unless you have a good reason to do so).